# Link attributes to attributes set

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm new in magento2 and I need your help.

In my InstallData.php, I created lot of product attributes with the following script :

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'my_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'My Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'option' => [
                'values' => [],
            ],
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Project\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Options',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => '',
            'group' => 'Custom Attributes'
        ]
    );
```

In parallel, I create attributes set with this script :

```
$setup->startSetup();
    $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

    $attributeSetNameArray = array();

    foreach ($attributeSetNameArray as $attributeSetName) {
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => $attributeSetName,
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
```

And now, I want to link attributes to attributes set. But an attribute can be link to several attributes set.

For exemple :

List of my attributes :

- Attr1
- Attr2
- Attr3
- Attr4
- Attr5

List of my attributes set :

- Default (the default attribute set)
- Attr_set1
- Attr_set2

And I want :

- In Default, all my attributes
- In Attr_set1, the attributes Attr1, Attr2, Attr3
- In Attr_set2, the attributes Attr1, Attr4

I want to make the links programmatically (not via the Back office). Someone have an idea ?

Comment: You can use this: 'attribute_set_id' => 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME', while creating attribute via script.

Comment: My attributes must be in several attributes set, so how can I do that ? I can't put an array in 'attribute_set_id' when I create my attribute...